# Creating a resuable navbar for multiple apps that compose a SPA

Tags: javascript, angularjs, architecture, bootstrapping

Im creating An angular spa app that's composed of small apps
and im having some thoughts.
since this is a spa i share a navbar across the app,
and since this app is splitted into minor apps and im having thoughts about how to make this navbar general.
 i thought about writing the navbar as a separate project with all of its data, uploading it to the web (artifactory or npm/git) and injecting it into each app as if it were a separate library.
or i tought about hosting all the urls on a server and getting them on the app or config pahse.
im not quite sure, can you share your experience?
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try using UI router to seperate the navbar to its own view, or put the navbar in a base abstract state that the rest of the states will derive from it